# Highlight Original Poster on question list

Tags: feature-request, users, user-interface, question-lists

When perusing the list of questions, often questions that may be of dubious quality (negative score, on hold etc) are shown as having been modified.  It would be useful to know if they have been modified by the question asker, perhaps providing additional information etc that make the question useful.

Right now, the only way to be sure is to click through to the question and have a look.  An easy solution would be to apply the same highlighting (the blue background) to the username in the question list as is done to the OP in comments on the question page.