# The original poster name is not shown in the front page list for edited questions

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, questions, front-page

When a question is edited, the name of the original poster is not shown on the front-pages. Instead the name of the user editing the question is shown.

This is kind of confusing, and it happens when I just browse quickly that I think a question is posted by the person last editing the question instead of the original poster.

I think it would be a good idea to list the questions as edited (and possibly by whom) but keep the name of the original poster.

Related to [Highlight Original Poster on question list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306271/highlight-original-poster-on-question-list).

Comment: If a question is bumped by being answered then it's the name of the answerer that appears with an "answered" label next to their name. The asker's name is effectively only shown when they first post the question.

Comment: Currently it depends on the question tab you are using: If you use `Newest` the OP is shown for every question. If you use `Active` the user which causes the last action (edit, answer, ...) is shown.

Comment: *when I just browse quickly that I think a question is posted by the person last editing the question instead of the original poster* — what concrete problem does this cause for you?

Comment: @Shepmaster Mostly I think its confusing. And I also think seeing more of the history of the question even at a quick glance would be more informational.

Comment: Maybe not so much on SO, but in several Stacks the message "modified 5 mins ago Community♦ 1" lets you know that it could well be a question from five years ago with a well-upvoted correct answer that was never accepted by an OP who hasn't been seen for four years and eleven months.